# strip out only left most letters from a string, only the left side letters

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I have files which is something like : "dslkj20111104-BATCH2244_20111113-091347.txt"
I only need "dslkj" and not the rest of the numbers or digits or .txt, how do I take that?

```
var onlyLetters = new String(fileName.Name.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

I tried this but it will give me ".txt" and "batch" too which I don't want any help is appreciated.

Comment: Regex would be `^[A-z]+` I don't know it works with C# though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [.TakeWhile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) instead of [.Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx).

```
var onlyLetters = new String(fileName.Name.TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx):

```
var leadingLetters = 
    new String(fileName.Name.TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

`TakeWhile` does exactly what it sounds like: it takes from the sequence while the condition is true. In this case, you want to take from the sequence of characters while the characters are letters, and stop as soon as you reach a non-letter.

Also, I recommend renaming your variable from `onlyLetters` to `leadingLetters`. `onlyLetters` is rather misleading given your plain-English description.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like:

```
string original = "slkj20111104-BATCH2244_20111113-091347.txt";
string stripped = Regex.Match(original,"^[a-z]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

Comment: Uhm, doesn't that achieve exactly the opposite than what is asked for?

Comment: @fge I indeed originally misread the bits to keep vs discard, but that was fixed several minutes ago ;p

Comment: Thanks Mark appreciate your help it works perfectly, but I chose Jason Meckley's answer because of prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[^a-z].*` by the empty string.

Comment: there is no `.replace` on a .NET / C# `string`

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[A-z]+");
var onlyLetters = r.Match(name);
```

Comment: this will not get only the leading letters it will also get non digit characters. try with this string original2 = "mmm_sales_12121212.txt";